# Creating list/array of class instances?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, class, search

I'm fairly new to C# and I have just learned about creating custom classes. The problem is, I can't figure out how to take the *40~65* instances of this class and put them in a list/array (whichever one I need) where I can locate and choose **one** based on an attribute defined in it.

Here's the class I have created right now:

```
public class Team
{
    protected int teamNum;
    protected double averageMatchPoints;
    protected string location;
    protected int matchesPlayed;
    protected int matchesPending;
    protected int blowouts;

    //Team Number
    public void SetNumber(int num)
    {
        teamNum = num;
    }

    public int GetNumber()
    {
        return teamNum;
    }

    //Average Points per match
    public void AverageMatchPoints(double p)
    {
        averageMatchPoints = p;
    }

    public double GetAverageMatchPoints()
    {
        return averageMatchPoints;
    }

    //location information
    public void SetLocation(string l)
    {
        location = l;
    }

    public string GetLocation()
    {
        return location;
    }

    //Number of Played Matches
    public void PlayedMatches(int mat)
    {
        matchesPlayed = mat;
    }

    public int GetPlayedMatches()
    {
        return matchesPlayed;
    }

    //Number of matches pending (not played)
    public void PendingMatches(int pen)
    {
        matchesPending = pen;
    }

    public int GetPendingMatches()
    {
        return matchesPending;
    }

    //Number of Blowouts (matches where the robot was disbaled for any number of reasons)
    public void SetBlowouts(int b)
    {
        blowouts = b;
    }

    public int GetBlowouts()
    {
        return blowouts;
    }
}
```

Now, if I had *40~65* of these teams competing at an event and I made an instance of this class for each one, how would I populate a combobox with each **team number** (teamNum) and then locate *one specific* team out of all the instances in the program by their **team numbers**?

Comment: Are you using Windows Forms? Also, when you add the teams to the combobox, are you trying to locate items via user selection or do you want to locate an item via code? What will appear in the combo besides the team number?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend a dictionary!

```
// Declared somewhere
private Dictionary<int, Team> _teamDictionary = new Dictionary<int, Team>();
.
.
.
//Initialization code - I assume you have gotten your teams from a database or somewhere?
foreach (var team in myTeamsList)
{
    _teamDictionary.Add(team.teamNum, team);
}
.
.
.
// Later when you want to locate a team:
var team = _teamDictionary[selectedTeamNum];
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried creating a List yet?

```
List<Team> Teams { get; set; }
```

You can then bind your combobox to the list/collection/IEnumerable of all the teams that you have. To initialize the teams up to 40/60 do the following?

```
for(int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
{
Team t = new Team();
t.Name = "Team 1";
t.TeamNumber = i + 1;
Teams.Add(t);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Team> allTheTeams = new List<Team>();

for(var i = 0; i < 65; i++){
  allTheTeams.Add(new Team { teamNum = i });
}
```

And to get the team with number 34:

```
allTheTeams.FirstOrDefault(x => x.teamNum == 34);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

Add a constructor to your class that takes the teamnumber:

(*this is the best solution if every team needs to have a number. So you can not forget to set the team number as you can not create an object of type team without setting the number in the constructor*)

```
public class Team
{
    protected int _teamNum;
    public Team(int teamNum)
    {
        _teamNum = teamNum;
    }

    public int getTeamNum()
    {
        return _teamNum;
    }

      //more logic
    }
```

Populate a [dictionary](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary), the comboBox and get a team for its number:

```
    Dictionary<int, Team> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, Team>();

    int teamNum = 1;
    // Add your Teams to a dictionary (example)
    dictionary.Add(teamNum ,new Team(teamNum++));
    dictionary.Add(teamNum, new Team(teamNum++));
    dictionary.Add(teamNum, new Team(teamNum++));

    // Populate a comboBox
    foreach(KeyValuePair<int,Team> kvp in dictionary)
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(kvp.Value.getTeamNum().ToString());
    }

    // get a team for a given teamNumer
    int targetTeamNumber = 2;
    if (dictionary.ContainsKey(targetTeamNumber))
    {
        Team team = dictionary[targetTeamNumber];
        // do something with the team
    }
```